# External CSS is not working ,I used internal CSS then it works but external CSS is not working

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <title>Creat Your Own Website</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('css', filename='css/style.css') }}"> 
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="Content">
            Here You can create your site for free
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use external CSS in this html code but when I use as internal it works but when I used it at external then it is not working ,pls help me out from this problem.

My CSS code-

```
#head{
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#004d4d;
 padding:5px;           
 margin:0px;   
       
 font-size:225%;  
 font-family:Times New Roman;
            
 }
      .Content{
margin-left:40px;
margin-right:40px;
margin-top:20px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Courier New;
}
```

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: In the View page source option, check whether the URL is correct or not. Try to open that URL in your browser. Or you can also check in networks tab in your developer console in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with `#head` in style.css. Let me know if you need anything different than this.

```css
body{
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#004d4d;
 padding:5px;           
 margin:0px;        
 font-size:225%;  
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 }
 
.Content{
margin-left:40px;
margin-right:40px;
margin-top:20px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Courier New;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <title>Creat Your Own Website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="Content">
            Here You can create your site for free
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```